# How to control velocity ratio when turning angle is θ?

Tags: kinematics

Im designing a differential steering mechanism for my robot. Supposing my robot is going in a straight line and I want it to change it direction by a certain angle( $θ$ in the diagram). What should the velocity ratio be of the 2 wheels so that it gradually turns and starts moving along a line that is $θ$ degrees to the initial line of movement?
If there's any ambiguity in the question please take a look at my earlier question which is similar. [How to design a differential steering mechanism?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1602/how-to-design-a-differential-steering-mechanism)
[image]

Comment: If I understand what you're asking the velocity ratio is the same as the travel distance ratio.  Draw the turn circle and compare the circumferences...

Comment: Are we talking about transitions from one straight line to another?  The missing parameter is the distance over which you want to do that.  So it's start a turn one way, and then go back to a straight line...

Comment: Yeah that't it. Basically its the ratio of the distances traveled by the 2 wheels while turning.

Comment: If you were to describe your problem in terms of the diagram in [my answer](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/1527/37) to [Line Follower optimization](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1524/37), then it might be easier to see what you are actually having a problem with.

Comment: @Mark Booth Actually I already have taken a look at your answer. You'd referred it to me previously. I've adopted your formula  $SL=rθ$ for my case but the problem only Im facing is that I dont have any way to get $r$, the radius of the turn. If I have that I can directly get the ratio of the 2 speeds.

Comment: Ah, I see where your problem is then, you need to choose $r$ according to how tight a turn you want. That's why @GuySirton was asking for the missing distance.

Comment: @Ghost: what Mark said.  If you don't know what r to choose, make it a variable and try a few.  If you're traveling at any speed you want it big, to reduce g forces.  In fact, you probably want it as big as possible, just on general principles (and keeping in mind that "as big as possible" may mean r=0, depending on the circumstance).

Answer (score 1):

In your [previous question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1602/350), we calculated the <s>velocity</s> speed ratio that would be required to make a turn of a given radius.  I'm going to reuse those formulas with *inner* and *outer* replacing *left* and *right*, and $d_{axle}$ replacing $A$.

In those terms, the ratio of the outer wheel's speed to the inner wheel's speed is still what it was before:
$$\frac{v_{outer}}{v_{inner}} = \frac{r+d_{axle}}{r}$$

However, in this question, you're trying to determine how much time should pass with the wheels turning at those speeds (in other words, following a circular path of a given $r$) before you come to a desired turning angle of $\theta$.

Here is the distance equation from before:

$$d_{inner} = \frac{\theta*2\pi{r}}{360}$$
$$v_{inner} = \frac{d_{inner}}{t} = \frac{\theta*2\pi{r}}{360*t}$$

So, solving for $t$:
$$ t = \frac{\theta*2\pi{r}}{360*v_{inner}}$$

This is essentially saying "how long will it take me to travel along a circular arc defined by $r$ and $\theta$ if I move at the given speed $v_{inner}$".

Now for the bad news: **achieving this is impossible in practice**.  The equations above are assuming that your acceleration is infinite, meaning that you would change your speed from $0$ to $v_{inner}$ instantly.  This has never happened.

If you need to be sure that you've reached a desired heading, you'll need to start working with sensors.  A GPS, a compass, or even wheel odometry would be good places to start.