# How Should I tie My quadcopter to some thing, to adjust pid on one axis

Tags: quadcopter, pid, balance

I am stuck in adjusting the PID of my quadcopter, I cant adjust them on the fly because it just get out of control. I am adjusting them while attaching my quadcopter to something.[image: this is how am I doing]

Is this method correct. Will the pid values required will be different on the fly or same. Please suggest me how to attach my quad to some thing.

Comment: Did you ever fix any of the [errors pointed out to you](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/8048/9720) in your PID code? Your untethered and tethered performance will be different because the tether adds to your mass and moment of inertia, but you should be able to tune to *stability* while it's tethered, then tune to *performance* with it untethered.

Comment: i have told you already that i have used the sample time in my pid code.
{
  now = millis(); 

  dt = now-ptime; 

  integ = integ+(error*dt) ;

  der = (error - prerror)/dt ;

  ptime = now; 

  pidy = (kp*error); 

  pidy+=(ki*integ );

  pidy+=(kd*der);

  if(pidy>500)pidy=500; 
  if(pidy<-500)pidy=-500;
  prerror=error;
}

Comment: i use no delay in my loop.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're trying to adjust the stability, you should make sure that your method of restraint isn't restricting the motion along that axis.

So, the preferred way to restrain a quadcopter is by connecting strings to the center of the body, above and below.  Here's an example:

[image: Quadcopter restraint]

You could also disable the motors on one axis and run a rope under each of the propeller shafts on that axis (sideways) to simulate the lift that those motors would provide while constraining any movement.

Comment: ok, but that will become very messy. tie the ropes to cielling and floor of the room. Is mine method correct? when i rotate the quad along that axis  by hand, there is no resistance felt.

Comment: You could tie the string between the floor an a table, or between your foot and your hand -- anywhere that leaves enough room for the quadcopter to change orientation on the string without hitting nearby objects.

Comment: MINE METHOD IS CORRECT?

Comment: See my update to the answer, but yes -- provided that your string is attached in the proper places to simulate the other axis, you should be OK with your method.

Answer (score 0):

It would stumble along the landing gear like that. Your UAV should be suspended in the air. Tie the harnesses to a heavy object on the sides of the UAV and keep them very taught to minimise any movement on it's other axis of rotation.