# calculating differential drive robot ICC position

Tags: kinematics, differential-drive

I don't understand how to calculate the ICC position with the given coordinates. I somehow just have to use basic trigonometry but I just can't find a way to calculate the ICC position based on the given parameters $R$ and $ \theta $.

[image]

Edit: Sorry guys if forgot to include the drawing of the situation. Yes, ICC = Instantaneous Center of Curvature.

Comment: I'm assuming that by ICC you mean the Instantaneous Centre of Curvature?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Leo. As it stands, it's not clear what you're asking. What is "ICC?" What is $R$ and $\theta$? Can you provide a diagram of your scenario or a more detailed problem statement? If, as @sempaiscuba states, you mean instantaneous center of curvature, then you *can't* find it based on a position and heading, if that's what $R$ and $\theta$ are, because you need more information. If $\theta$ is something like an Ackermann steering angle, then you still need more information, like the wheel base. Please *edit your question* to include the missing information.

Comment: Does [my answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/1527/37) to [this question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1524) help?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm going to work on the assumption that you are trying to calculate the Instantaneous Centre of Curvature, and that the values of $R$ and $\theta$ that you have been given are the distance from the ICC to the mid-point of the wheel axle and the direction of travel relative to the x-axis.

That should correspond with the diagram below, taken from [Computational Principles of Mobile Robotics](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0cggAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Dudek and Jenkin:

[image: diff drive robot]

Now, provided you know the position of the robot $(x,y)$ you can find the location of the ICC by trigonometry as:

[image: trigonometry]

$$
ICC = [x - R sin(\theta), y + R cos(\theta)]
$$

---

In the more usual case, we can measure the velocities of the left and right wheels, $V_{r}$ and $V_{l}$. From the diagram, we can see that:

$$
V_{r} = \omega (R + \frac{l}{2})
$$

$$
V_{l} = \omega (R - \frac{l}{2})
$$

Where $\omega$ is the rate of rotation about the ICC, $R$ is the distance from the ICC to the mid-point of the wheel axle, and $l% is the distance between the centres of the wheels.

Solving for $R$ and $\omega$ gives:

$$
R = \frac{l}{2} \frac{V_{l} + V_{r}}{V_{r} - V_{l}}
$$

$$
\omega = \frac{V_{r} - V_{l}}{l}
$$

Comment: Okay Thankyou, im impressed you knew so fast the exact page from referenced book.  But as I understand $ \theta $ is the angle between the x-axis and the robots direction. Shouldn't the angle then be 1- $ \theta $ instead of just  $ \theta $ ?

Comment: like here in this picture:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]   

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVqD0.png

Comment: @Leo As to the book, it's not the first time I've had people mention it. The authors' use of $R$ and $\theta$ in this instance often causes confusion with their more usual use as polar coordinates.

Comment: @Leo OK, I've corrected the diagram (again!). I must really need some sleep! (Not trying to edit pictures and Latex on a 7" mobile phone would probably help too!). The angle is actually $\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta$, rather than just $\theta$. The remaining angle of the triangle shown in red is then $\theta$ which allows you to use basic trigonometry to obtain the result in the formula.

Comment: Sorry of course i meant $ \pi /2 $ instead of $ 1 $ too, sorry for that mistake. Okay now it makes sense to me since i just didnt recognize the angle $ \theta $ in the ICC corner. Thankyou!